# Get Pane of G_MAP_MARKER_MOUSE_TARGET_PANE in google map V3

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I am migrating to Google maps V3 from V2. I need to add a `G_MAP_MARKER_MOUSE_TARGET_PANE` pane in the maps. following is the V2 code:

```
mapPanel = myMap.GMap.getPane(G_MAP_MARKER_MOUSE_TARGET_PANE);
AddItem(mapPanel);
```

I need the V3 code to get the `MOUSE_TARGET_PANE`. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for `google.maps.MapPanes.overlayMouseTarget`.

Here's a list of [all the V3 Maps API overlay panes](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#MapPanes).

Naturally, the V3 overlays work a bit differently from the V2 ones. Here's a [V3 example](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/overlay-simple).